# How do I configure proxy settings for Java in Solaris to handle Proxy Auto Config (PAC) scripts?

Tags: java, proxy, solaris

I would like to configure Java proxy settings **on Solaris** to use a Proxy Auto Config (PAC) scriptt.

[I have found instructions for making the settings on a Windows machine using the Java control panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/5000020600.xml), but am having trouble finding where/how to make the same setting changes on a Solaris Java install.

I would like to use the Proxy Auto Config (PAC) script, rather than manually setting proxy info per connection, or using a single proxy.  I have a need to leverage multiple proxies for different types of URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly the system proxy selector [does not handle PAC/WPAD/JS specifications](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.net.devel/769), confirmed by my testing with Windows or MacOS X.  Even on Java6, which includes a JavaScript interpreter.

I'm hoping **[proxy-vole](http://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/)** http://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/ may do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. Let me know if that works out. My "solution" was going to be to re-create the logic in the JS in a custom proxy selector java class, but I'd like to just point to the JS file and have it work the way browsers do.

Answer (score 5):

The article you have provided is about the the *Java Plug-in* (i.e. the Java runtime environment for browsers) that can be configured through the *Java Plug-in Control Panel* and applies to:

> **Platform(s):** All Platforms

So, it's really not Windows specific.

Now, if your question is "How do I start the Java Plug-in Control Panel on Solaris", the answer is:

> You can run the Control Panel by launching the ControlPanel executable file. In the Java 2 SDK, this file is located at
>
> ```
> <SDK installation directory>/jre/bin/ControlPanel
> ```
>
> For example if your Java 2 SDK is installed at `/usr/j2se`, launch the Control Panel with this command:
>
> ```
> /usr/j2se/jre/bin/ControlPanel
> ```

But usually people are not using Solaris for surfing so I'm not really sure that this is what you're looking for (actually, I didn't understand clearly what you want to do).

If you are going to connect programmatically, please note that Java uses two system properties to designate a proxy: `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`. For applets, these are automatically set to use the browser's settings. However, in an application you need to set them yourself:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("http.proxyHost", "proxyhostname");
props.put("http.proxyPort", "proxyhostport");
```

---

As per comment, my understanding is that you want to use a PAC file. To use a Proxy auto-config from Java code and/or Ant with Java 1.5+, you can configure the proxy at the "OS level" and set the system property `java.net.useSystemProxies` to `true` (see section **4) ProxySelector** of [Java Networking and Proxies](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)) or the `-autoproxy` option for Ant. This will make the Java code and/or Ant use the OS proxies.

To setup your Solaris host, if you are using Gnome 2.X, you can configure proxies globally through the user interface (System > Preferences > Network Proxy). If you're not using Gnome, setup the following environment variable:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url
```

To specify a list of non proxy hosts (if necessary), setup this variable (this is an example):

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local
```

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to delegate the logic for selecting the appropriate proxy to an existing proxy script, so that I don't have to replicate and maintain the logic in code. I will be running some JEE code on a Solaris server and/or ANT with -autoproxy switch to fetch HTTP resources through different proxies.  I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but suspect that the ControlPanel settings will work.

Comment: I think that you need to configure your Solaris host (not the Java Plug-in) to use your proxy PAC file globally. Then, set the `java.net.useSystemProxies` system property in your Java code (in the case of Ant, this is what the `-autoproxy` option does). This tells the JVM to use the system proxy settings. See section 4) ProxySelector of http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: So, you appear to be correct in that settings for the ControlPanel do not appear to affect normal JRE HTTP operations, even with -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true at startup. I'm at a loss for how to configure Solaris to use the autoproxy PAC file/URL. Google isn't turning up anything. Maybe that should be a separate SO question, or maybe something for ServerFault...

Comment: I've added some details to use the PAC file.

Comment: If you can't add the `-autoproxy` option to Ant (e.g. you're within Eclipse), you could also use the [`<setproxy>` task of Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html).